# FDT can't find flash player

Tags: flash, fdt

I used FlashDevelop for 3 years and everything work well. Now I have to use Mac . I have some troubles , I am new to FDT, I can't build my project.
I downloaded a AIR-Flex combo SDK from internet for I have some trouble to copy AIR3.5 SDK into Flex4.6 folder. Some folder/files are replaced but not merged.

## Case 1: AIR Project.

I create a AIR project, chose run on desktop (not device) and run project with no window appear. The console's info is wired.

Run mode:

```
Starting Launcher FDTTest-FDTTest.

Using: Flex SDK Compiler
Starting Incremental Build of FDTTest-FDTTest.

File /Users/Feng/Documents/Workspace/FlashWork/FDTTest/bin/FDTTest.swf has not changed.
Build successful.

Launching AIR Debug Launcher
/Users/Feng/Documents/Tools/flex_sdk_4.6_air3.5_fp11.5/bin/adl
    -nodebug
    -profile
    extendedMobileDevice
    -screensize
    480x762:480x800
    /Users/Feng/Documents/Workspace/FlashWork/FDTTest/bin/FDTTest-app.xml
    /Users/Feng/Documents/Workspace/FlashWork/FDTTest/bin
```

debug mode:

```
[Info] Listening to port 7935.
[Info] Could not connect to the player, will try to connect for the next 72000 ms
```

## Case 2: SWF Project

I create a swf project and can see the window with external player(java) but not adobe flash player.

I downloaded the latest adobe flash debug player and installed them on my Mac OSX 10.8.
But I can't find the flash player standalone file when I try to set the path for FDT -> Preferences -> FDT -> Tools -> Flash -> FlashPlayer.

I have checked user/library and other folders but can't find it. I have struggled for hours. Thanks.

Comment: For case 1, can you see the ADL process running in your process viewer? Also what happens if you run this via the terminal: '/Users/Feng/Documents/Tools/flex_sdk_4.6_air3.5_fp11.5/bin/adl'? For case 2, the External SWF viewer is is actually a web browser - using the web-based flash player plugin. To launch the standalone, you'll need to have the prefs point to the stand alone player (usually somewhere in the SDK) and then make sure your launcher has the Flash Player chosen to launch. Tell me more about your situation and I can leave an answer.

Comment: Also, FDT has a button to merge your AIR SDK. Make sure your permissions are still set to read, write, execute before & after. http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/AIR_SDK_Merging

Comment: Never mind, I spent 10 hours on FDT and failed, but I setup everything on Flash Builder 4.7 in 10 minutes and it even run on native iOS simulator (not AIR simulator). But still thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

Download the file:

http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html
   Download standalone debugger for Mac OS X 32-bit (DMG, 14.5 MB)

Install the flash player to your application folder.

You may find the Flash Player Debugger binary here:

> /Application/Flash Player.app/Contents/MacOS/Flash Player Debugger

Please note that browse only works on application level. 
You need to use the direct path of the debugger.